# 'CustomUser' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

## serializers.py

```
class UserprofileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['id','mobile','pincode', 'address','profileimage','coverImg']

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    profile = UserprofileSerializer(required=True,)
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'created_at','profile']
```

## views.py

```
class profiledata(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                      mixins.ListModelMixin,
                      generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
    authentication_classes = [
        JWTAuthentication, TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=self.request.user)
        return user

    def get(self, request, id=None):
       if id:
            return self.retrieve(request)
       else:
            item = self.list(request)
            return item
```

when i try to get single data and serializers them,  this time generated the error '*CustomUser*' object is not iterable

Comment: Exactly what should the "list" mode do? It seems a bit non-sensical that there is both a list and a retrieve, whereas you always return (at most) one user.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
....
    def get_queryset(self):
        return CustomUser.objects.filter(email=self.request.user)

    def get(self, request, id=None):
        if id:
            return self.retrieve(request)
        else:
            return self.list(request)
```